# possible loss of precision-with mod- (but it's not)

Tags: java, precision, long-integer

So this the line with the precision error fault;

A[i]= m % 3;

m is long
A is int[];
And my error is 
error: possible loss of precision
            A[i]= m % 3.
required int
found long.

How can I have error when the only potential answers are 0,1,2?
Isn't there another way than declaring A as long[]?
It's a potentially big array so I don't want that (in fact I would even prefer for A to be short[])
Also I tried error:  A[i]= m % 3L , but same result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a 'int' in parenthesis mean when giving a value to an int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875960/what-does-a-int-in-parenthesis-mean-when-giving-a-value-to-an-int)

Comment: Java doesn't know that you are modulating over 3, if it was a number greater than 2^8 it would cause an error as A cannot hold this big a number. Either ignore it or cast the modula into an int: `A[i] = (int) (m%3);`

Answer (score 2):

The compiler doesn't look at the result, it looks at the type. The type of `m%3` is `long`, and you are trying to put it into an `int`.

So, the compiler is angry, because potentially, the value stored in a `long`is bigger than the one you can store into an `int`.

In order to remove the problem, you have to cast the result back into an `int`:

```
A[i] = (int) (m % 3);
```

However, you can do this because you know the result is 0,1 or 2. If you do not know the value of the `long` you are casting, you may have an integer overflow:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long l = Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1L;
    System.out.println(l); 
    // 2147483648
    System.out.println((int)l);
    // -2147483648
}
```

Comment: Even if you write System.out.println(l); without casting it to int, result will be -2147483648. Because Integer.MAX_VALUE is int and 1 is also int. Therefore the result of the summation is int and it is overflowed at the moment of addition