# Java program error: possible loss of precision

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am trying to figure out why I am getting this loss of precision error in my Java program.

This is the error:

```
error: possible loss of precision
         int digit = num/Math.pow(10,i-1)%10;
                                         ^
  required: int
  found:    double
1 error
```

This is the code clip inside a for loop

```
for(int i = 1; i<=String.valueOf(num).length(); i++)
{
    int digit = num/Math.pow(10,i-1)%10;
    //etc
}
```

I want to keep digit as an integer variable, and I tried to declare digit outside the loop, and I also tried casting it into an integer which didn't work. I did try doing it as:

```
digit += num/Math.pow(10,i-1)%10; //with digit declare outside of loop
```

which worked magically, but I don't want to increment it, instead I want it to contain the digit which I can use for later. Is there something I'm missing here? Please explain.

Comment: Use `int digit = num/(int)Math.pow(10,i-1)%10;`. [Math.pow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double)) returns a double. I'm assuming `num` is an int.

Comment: Casting is your solution. The lack of errors on `+=` is explained [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8710619/5743988).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [possible loss of precision-with mod- (but it's not)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548399/possible-loss-of-precision-with-mod-but-its-not)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to run your code as follows:

```
int digit = (int) (num/Math.pow(10,i-1)%10);
```

And it worked as expected, i.e. it iterated through the digits of your variable num (which I assumed as int).

When you use the += operator, it works not because of magic, but because of automatic type promotion. You can read more about it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Comment: I forgot the parenthesis for the object reference when I tried casting it the first time. But it works fine now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The easist fix is to simply cast

```
num/Math.pow(10,i-1)%10;
```

into an Integer. You can do this by adding (int) before it:

```
 int digit = (int) num/Math.pow(10,i-1)%10;
```

As to why this happens: Math.pow is defined as a double and won't convert a Double value into an Integer value without explicitly telling it to.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.pow` returns a double, and all your other operands in the expression are integral types. To fix the compiler error, explicitly cast the result of `Math.pow` to an int, as indicated by the other answers.

Side note. Don't use `Math.pow` to find 10 to the power of i-1, because floating-point exponentiation is unnecessarily expensive. Instead, multiply by 10 on every iteration, like so:

```
int r = 1;
for(int i = 1; r < num; i++, r *= 10) {
    int digit = num / r % 10;
    // ...
}
```